# Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core Application shows only Framework Versions

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I will create a new Project with .NET Core 2.2.
But I can select only .NET Framework Versions. 
I installed .NET Core 2.2 and restart the Visual Studio.
Still .NET Core is not available.
I installed the 64bit 2.2.107 version.
When I want to install again I get ask if I want to repair, what is telling me that the installation was successful.

**Why I cant choose .NET Core instead of Framework?**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Create ASP.NET Core Web Application (first option). In next window you should have option to change .net core version.

Comment: Thanks @assassin1909! :-)